# Responsive Layout - nav element positioning

Tags: css, layout, web, responsive-design, nav

I am just starting to work with responsive layouts and had a specific question related to nav elements.

If I had a block of code like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When viewing this on a high resolution computer screen we would have a 2x3 grid created by the navs. Namely, each nav would be on its own "line" and all three elements of each nav would be to the right or left of each other.

With a responsive layout, if the size of the window was shrunk significantly, say, to an iPhone resolution, assuming correct proportioning, will the nav elements awkwardly change so that that view would look something like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm just looking for a high-level understanding of how this new layout practice works specifically for nav elements. I am hoping to create something like this for a website I am making but if this is going to happen I want to create code such that I'll have that 2x3 matrix at high resolutions and a 3x2 for lower resolutions, moving to a 6x1 for extremely small resolutions.

If this is the case, is there a way to specify, for specific screen resolutions, different html? I know we can specify specific CSS for different resolutions, but in this case I'm not sure changing the CSS will do what I need it to do.

Comment: You should keep one `nav` and one `ul`.  Then float and size the `li`s appropriately for the resolution you are targeting via css.  For example in the 1x6 you wouldn't float them at all and instead likely apply a width of 100% to allow them to stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I understand that your `ul`s have a block display, while `li`s have an inline display.
This causes the nav/ul to have a rectangular block around it, avoiding the 2x3 layout to happen.
What you really want, as Jrod pointed out in a comment, is a single rectangular block wrapping all your li items, and having the browser arrange them.

You can either achieve this by putting all lis together, or better by changing the ul and nav display properties to inline, while putting a container around the two navs to ensure they ultimately are grouped by a block.

```
div.container { display: block; }
nav, ul, li { display: inline; }
```

Be advised that this solution might also create a 4x2 grid with two empty cells, so make sure you limit the outer block to the width of three lis:

```
li { width: 150px; /* or whatever */ }
div.container { max-width: 450px; /* three lis at most */ }
```